# How to download sbt plugin depdendency without SBT version in the dependency URL?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to use an sbt plugin that I've published in my private mavenrepository

The plugin is configured as following :

```
    val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++
                      Seq (organization  := buildOrganization,
                           scalaVersion  := buildScalaVersion,
                           version       := buildVersion,
                           publishMavenStyle := true,
                           pomIncludeRepository := { _ => true },
                           scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-encoding", "utf8"),
                           publishTo     := Some("External" at "http://xx.yy.net/archiva/repository/external"),
                           credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
                          )
```

With "sbt publish", the plugin is deployed here : 
http://xx.yy.net/archiva/repository/external/templemore/sbt-cucumber-parent_2.10/0.8.0/sbt-cucumber-parent_2.10-0.8.0.pom

Then I use my plugin from another SBT app. In my plugins.sbt, I add :

```
addSbtPlugin("templemore" %% "sbt-cucumber-plugin" % "0.8.0")
```

But it fails because SBT (or Ivy) is looking at an URL with teh SBT version of the plugin  (0.13) inside :

```
tried
[warn]   http://xx.yy.net/archiva/repository/external/templemore/sbt-cucumber-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.8.0/sbt-cucumber-plugin-0.8.0.pom
```

1) How can I prevent SBT to add its version in the dependency URL?

2) Or, if 1 is not possible, how can I set my SBT plugin configuration to deploy the artifact to archiva with the right URL pattern?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have `sbtPlugin := true` in your `build.sbt` ?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy this artifact : https://github.com/skipoleschris/xsbt-cucumber-plugin/blob/master/project/Build.scala

Indeed there is a "sbtPlugin := true" but only for a submodule, maybe it's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you have to publish it with `sbt-cucumber-plugin/publish`, which will execute publish in a sub-project `sbt-cucumber-plugin` of the parent project.